# Cakephp 3: Paginator links

Tags: cakephp, pagination

this is my index() function:

```
$this->paginate = [
        'conditions' => [
            'Items.state_id' => $state,
        ],
        'contain' => ['Accounts', 'Creditors', 'States', 'Bankaccounts' => ['joinType' => 'LEFT']],
        'order' => ['Items.account_id ASC', 'Items.creditor_id ASC', 'Items.payuntil ASC']
    ];
    $this->set('items', $this->paginate($this->Items));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['items']);
```

It works fine until I want to use the pagination links to page 2:

My view:

```
<div class="paginator">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <?= $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('vorherige')) ?>
        <?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
        <?= $this->Paginator->next(__('nächste') . ' >') ?>
    </ul>
    <p><?= $this->Paginator->counter('Seite {{page}} von {{pages}}') ?></p>
</div>
```

This is the output in a browser:

```
<a href="/items?page=2&amp;sort=0&amp;direction=Items.account_id+ASC">2</a>
```

But this will lead to a sql error:

```
    WHERE 
  Items.state_id = 1 
ORDER BY 
  asc 
LIMIT 
  20 OFFSET 0
```

There is an empty ORDER BY option.

If I change the above link to only: /items?page=2
it works as expected.

So what is wrong here? 
How can I fix this?
Please advice :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct syntax is

```
'order' => ['Items.account_id' => 'ASC', 'Items.creditor_id' => ' ASC', 'Items.payuntil' => ' ASC']
```

you'll stop getting your error but you'll find this issue:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/7324

Comment: Great!! Thanks so much!